# Is it possible to use TinyXML2 (or any other library) to convert structure or class directly to XML file and viceversa?

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I have number of structures that look like this:

```
struct A
{
    long lValueA;
    BOOL bValueA;
    CString strValueA;
}; 
struct B
{
    long lValueB;
    BOOL bValueB;
    CString strValueB;
}; 
struct C
{
    A a;
    vector<B> vecB;
};
```

Is it possible to use TinyXML2 (or any other library) to convert it into XML file without manually pass each member variable from **struct C**? what I want will look like this:

```
main()
{
  C c;
  // Some code to initialise member variable of struct C

  // pass object/structure to XML parser to get XML file.
  Some_XML_Library_Object.parse( c ); 
  Some_XML_Library_Object.SaveFile("FilePath/Name.xml");

  // Also it would be nice if we can update values in structure or class directly like this
  const char* XML_File_Path = "FilePath/Name.xml";
  Some_XML_Library_Object.updateValueOfStructureFromXML(&c,XML_File_Path)
}
```

The XML File produce look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <lValueA>
        value
    </lValueA>

    <bValueA>
        value
    </bValueA>

    <strValueA>
        value
    </strValueA>
</A>

<B>
    <lValueB>
        value
    </lValueB>
      ...
      ...
</B>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer: no (for TinyXML anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use boost::serialisation to do something like what you asked...

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html

it has extensive capabilities for handling XML (and other formats) from the above page:

> In this tutorial, we have used a particular archive class -
>   text_oarchive for saving and text_iarchive for loading. text archives
>   render data as text and are portable across platforms. In addition to
>   text archives, the library includes archive class for native binary
>   data and xml formatted data. Interfaces to all archive classes are all
>   identical. Once serialization has been defined for a class, that class
>   can be serialized to any type of archive.

Edit: you'd handle objects and serialize them rather than manipulate the XML directly to change values.